# How to find duplicate values while importing excel and displays an error message on the same table where imported data displays?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC with C#, I am trying to import an excel sheet and validate those sheet and displays the excel data along with error message on one column in a table. If got any error my selection checkbox will not available, so the user cannot select and save the particular record. my page is actually working. What is my issue right now is, I wanna add Unique id validation. which means I have one Id column, where I don't want duplicate value. I added validation to check with my table and if found any same id, it returns an error message. but, **if let say, user upload duplicate values on the excel sheet when they upload means, how to find out while uploading and how to prevent them from adding duplicate id records.**

my sample coding below.

```
if (theFile != null && theFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
    try
    {
        string[,] data = ExportUtil.GetData(theFile);

        int rowValue = data.GetLength(0);
        int colValue = data.GetLength(1);

        Info _I;
        ViewModel _VM;


        for (int i = 0; i < rowValue; i++)
        {

            _VM= new ViewModel();
           // _VM.Id = i;
            _VM.Id = data[i, 0].ToString() != null ? data[i, 0].ToString() : "";
            _VM.Description = data[i, 1].ToString() != null ? data[i, 1].ToString() : "";


            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_VM.Id))
            {
                _VM.Message = "Id cannot be empty" + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }
            _ID = TagInfo.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_VM.Id) && a.Id.ToUpper() == _VM.Id.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (_ID != null)
            {
                _VM.Message += "Duplicate ID" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                _ID =null;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_VM.Description))
            {
                _VM.Message += "Description cannot be empty" + System.Environment.NewLine;
            }


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_VM.Message))
            {
                _VM.Message = string.Format("{0}{1}", "Row Number " + (i + 1) + " has " + Environment.NewLine, _VM.Message);

            }

            listvm.Add(_VM);

        }

        TempData["ID_DOWNLOAD"] = listvm;


    }
}
```

`_ID` I declared with table name `TableID _ID`; above the try block. kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Add your unique ID to a list of int then find duplicate ids in that list by linq

```
var duplicateKeys = list.GroupBy(x => x)
                        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                        .Select(group => group.Key);
```

if **duplicateKeys** count is greater than 1 then you know there are some IDs duplicated.

Comment: I got the excel values in a model, my table name Info, column name Id and the model name ViewModel. Can you please update your query with my details , as I already confused with keys and values.. TIA

Comment: Also how to display on the row where duplicate values occur.. I need to accept 1st value, if 2nd and 3 rd row got duplicate value means, I need 2 display on the 2nd and 3rd row message box, that "Duplicate of row number1"

Comment: In this Linq query I need to use X, group,list and key all as a keyword or need to apply my list names? @Bhuban Shrestha